# Using ls -ld with find still prints out the files in the directory

Tags: find

I'm using find to list all the files with a given UID and GID. I'm storing the file list in a temp file because I need to print out different attributes of this file set.
One of these attributes is the files that have the install GID. I put the contents of the temp file into an array:

```
a=$( < $tmpfile)
```

The contents of tmpfile are like this for the cups package:

```
/usr/share/cups
/usr/share/cups/banners
/usr/share/cups/data
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/apple-touch-icon.png
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/cups.css
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/cups-printable.css
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/de
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/de/index.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/es
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/es/index.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/accounting.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/api-admin.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/api-filter.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/api-ppd.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/api-raster.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/cgi.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/cupspm.html
/usr/share/cups/doc-2.2.6/help/encryption.html
```

and so on ....

and then search the array like so:

```
echo "files with group install"
for file in ${a[@]}; do
  find $file -type f -user $userid -group install -exec ls -l {} \;
  find $file -type d -user $userid -group install -exec ls -ld {} \;
done
```

The second find here prints out the files under the directory and so any sub-directories with the install GID are printed twice. This is despite the presence of ls -ld. So the result for cups looks like:

```
drwxrwxr-t 16 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups/ppdc
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:21 /usr/share/cups/model
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups/banners
drwxrwxr-t 3 cups install 4096 Dec 13 16:53 /usr/share/cups/drv
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec 13 16:53 /usr/share/cups/mime
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups/data
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:26 /usr/share/cups/usb
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups/banners
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups/data
drwxrwxr-t 3 cups install 4096 Dec 13 16:53 /usr/share/cups/drv
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec 13 16:53 /usr/share/cups/mime
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:21 /usr/share/cups/model
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:28 /usr/share/cups/ppdc
drwxrwxr-t 2 cups install 4096 Dec  1 17:26 /usr/share/cups/usb
```

I know find is recursive but surely it should honor the exec command and just print the long form of the directory.

```
for (( i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do
#    for file in ${a[@]}; do
 find ${a[i]} -user $userid -group install -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
 find ${a[i]} -user $userid -group install -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
done
```

gives the same result.

Comment: s/enter echo/echo/

Comment: Do not comment on your own question; edit it instead.

Comment: Please: Edit your question and provide an example of the first find, or some entries in tmpfile.

Comment: You should use `for file in "${a[@]}"` and `find "$file"`

Comment: Using double quotes concatenates all the filenames with \n between each filename.

Comment: The last `do` should be a `done`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, That `a` isn't an array.

Comment: No, you're correct -  it is a list of files separated by new lines

Comment: but I can treat it as though it were an array - and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find $file -type d -user $userid -group install -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

This will recurse into `$file`, and run `ls -ld` on all directories within it. So if the list you loop over also contains the subdirectories, you'll get them again. First when `find` recurses starting at the main directory, then for every time the subdirectories are listed.

Compare:

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/subdir
$ for f in dir1 dir1/subdir ; do find "$f" -type d -exec ls -1d {} \; ; done
dir1
dir1/subdir
dir1/subdir
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do here, for listing just the file currently being processed (in `$file`), you don't need `find` at all, just `ls -ld $file` should do. Though if you're using `find` to only print files owned by a given user, you might use `-maxdepth 0` to prevent `find` from recursing. At all.

```
$ for f in dir1 dir1/subdir ; do find "$f" -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec ls -1d {} \; ; done
dir1
dir1/subdir
```

But then I wonder if it would be better to just find the directory/-ies under which all the files are (`/usr/share/cups`, here) and just run `find -user ... -group ... -exec ls -ld {} +` on that.

---

As for `a`, the assignment `a=$( < $tmpfile)` just assigns a string to `a`. Which in the shell is the same as `a[0]`, and `${#a[@]}` also just returns `1` since a scalar is in sense a single-element array. To make it an actual array, you'd need to assign `a=( $(< $tmpfile) )`, but that just makes the splitting on whitespace happen earlier.

You might want to use `while read ...` to read the input file instead. See [BashFAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: I'm trying to pull out all the cups files that are set with GID=install and a whole bunch of different attributes that I haven't shown. Adding -maxdepth 0 fixed the problem. Thanks.